# How to run regression on few factors with many training factors using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have recently been working on trying to get sklearn working with my data. I have 609 columns of data for each of my ~20k rows. The data is formatted as follows:

- Rows 0-7 are each a different type of "output" (each of 1-8 are independently based on the "inputs")
- Rows 8-608 are the "input values", i.e., the values which produce the first seven columns' outputs.

All these values are found in a file called `unlabelled.csv`, or really a CSV of whatever name you chose to assign it.

So what I've been trying to do is run SGD regression on it, as follows:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model as linmod
import numpy as np
rawdata=open('unlabelled.csv','r')
dataset=np.loadtxt(rawdata,delimiter=",") # this is where there's a hang
factzero=dataset[:,0]
factone=dataset[:,1]
facttwo=dataset[:,2]
factthree=dataset[:,3]
factfour=dataset[:,4]
factfive=dataset[:,5]
factsix=dataset[:,6]
factseven=dataset[:,7]
base=dataset[:,8:608]
facts=[factzero,factone,facttwo,factthree,factfour,factfive,factsix,factseven]
clf=linmod.SGDRegressor()
for fact in facts:
    clf.fit(base,fact)
```

Now, this returns (at the python command line, anyway):

```
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25,
       random_state=None, shuffle=True, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to go forwards from here; I want to be able to give all the "input" values and receive some sort of prediction of "output" values after training on my dataset. I've tried to scour the web for some documentation on this, but can't ascertain how to do it exactly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry but questions about how to use particular software products are off-topic, here. I'm not sure if it would be on-topic elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry, I realize this now. I will try putting it in StackOverflow, where it should be on topic

Comment: OK -- you can either delete this question and repost it, or click the flag button and ask the moderators to move it across for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to store the trained models somewhere. You can do this by replacing the last two lines of your code by this:

```
models = [clf.fit(base, fact) for fact in facts]
```

After training your models, you need some input data upon which you'll make your prediction. Say, you have some unseen data set called `unseen_data.csv`. Assuming you have that and you've loaded it in some variable `unseen_dataset`, you can use that to make your predictions as follows:

```
predicted_facts = [model.predict(unseen_dataset) for model in models]
```

Now `predicted_facts` will contain your predictions.

You can find much more detailed information in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html).

---

A couple of tips:

- You should consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) -- it makes it easier to work with large data sets.
- You can save yourself some typing by replacing

  ```
  factzero=dataset[:,0]
  factone=dataset[:,1]
  facttwo=dataset[:,2]
  factthree=dataset[:,3]
  factfour=dataset[:,4]
  factfive=dataset[:,5]
  factsix=dataset[:,6]
  factseven=dataset[:,7]
  facts=[factzero,factone,facttwo,factthree,factfour,factfive,factsix,factseven]
  ```

  with

  ```
  facts = [fact for fact in dataset[:, :8]]
  ```

  The latter is also way easier to read.